# Magento Search Not Working with One Word

Tags: duplicate

Wondering if someone could help with this...

TL;DR: Is it possible to duplicate a searched query in Magento php files without the user knowing. E.g. Searching 'Adidas' actually searches 'Adidas Adidas' but only shows as 'Adidas' to the user.

Ok, so I know the Magento CE search isn't great and needs a little help, but one thing I can't get working is a search with one word.

It's really bizarre. I'm using the 'like' search. I've changed the necessary code from 'OR' to 'AND' which helped a bit but I can't seem to show any results if I type a brand name such as 'Adidas'.

However, if I type 'Adidas Adidas' all the relevant products show up.

So I'm curious, is it possible to change some code so it duplicates the word being search for, without the user knowing that the word has been duplicated?

And please ask if none of that makes sense, I've just tried to give as much info as possible.

Comment: The fact that you need to duplicate the words to get result indicates there is a bigger issue with your search. It should just work with one word. Finding out what that issue is will probably give you a better solution than duplicating the search query

Comment: How would I find that issue? I agree that there is a bigger problem at the heart of it all, I'm just trying to think of a solution to it, and that's what I came up with for the moment.

Comment: Check for any core modifications or 3rd party modules that might influence it. And check the Magento logs for any errors or warnings

Comment: There aren't any 3rd party modules that affect the search and I haven't made any core changes (we know that's a big no no in Magento), will check the logs now though. I guess I'm just looking for a quick fix for the time being before trying out B00MER's solution using SOLR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sander mentioned, if your needing to duplicate values for whatever reason means you need to re-evaluate your approach and problem space.

Don't skimp on user searches its a core sales driver for e-commerce.  With that said, MySQL `Fulltext` is very limited to search most are accustomed to today. While it serves its purpose, Magento rely's heavily on MySQL's built-in search functionality and is best to use a more geared package for Search like Lucene(Elasticsearch, Solr), Sphinx, etc.

While this doesn't directly address your problem, hopefully will steer you in a better direction with more customization tools built-in to fine tune results without the need of custom code.

- https://gist.github.com/jeremyfelt/8230088
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: I would like to use SOLR if I'm honest but would have no idea how to implement it, even after reading the docs. The search actually works quite well, it's just this one little thing (even though it's quite a big deal)

Comment: I should also reiterate that I'm using the 'like' function of Magento search at the moment as it seems to work better than 'fulltext' or 'combine'.

Comment: Went for elastic search, seems to have solved the problem, thanks B00MER